# taxonomy vocabulary access

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

I want a role to have access to

- add and view terms to any vocabulary,
- the overview `admin/structure/taxonomy/foo_vocabulary` for sorting the terms by draging

but deny the access to edit the vocabulary or its fields. its like `administer-taxonomy` permission without the option to edit a vocabulary. [TAC](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) wont help.

Comment: This is a duplicate of

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23018/how-to-grant-a-role-permission-to-edit-terms-in-a-specific-vocabulary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taxonomy access fix](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix)

> This module
>
> -adds 1 permission per vocabulary: "add terms in X"
>
> -changes the way vocabulary specific permissions are handled
>
> -changes the Taxonomy admin pages' access checks
>
> -alters the vocabularies overview table to show only what you have access to edit or delete
>
> The module does what native Taxonomy lacks: more specific Taxonomy permissions (and checking them correctly).

Answer (score 1):

I know, this question is pretty old, but I was looking for a solution by myself.

Maybe someone is looking as well: http://drupal.org/project/vppr
This module provides some new permission settings just for viewing terms which is exactly what I was looking for.